# uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Given f is a differentiable function. Define $$f_n(x)=n\left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right)$$, prove that $f_n$ is uniformly converge to $f'$
I have tried to make these equations:
$n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))=\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)}{1/n}$ and taking limits as n $\to\infty$ but i got stuck to prove its uniform convergent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true only when $f'$ is uniformly continuous.(Use MVT)

For,

By MVT, there exists $\varepsilon_n \in (x,x+1/n)$ such that $$\Big|\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}-f'(x)\Big|=|f'(\varepsilon_n)-f'(x)|$$

How to make the RHS small in order to make uniform convergent?

Ans: Using uniform continuity of $f'$

Otherwise, consider, for example, $f(x)=x^3$ on $\Bbb R$. Then $$\sup_x \Big|\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}-f'(x)\Big|=\sup_\color{red}x \Big|\frac{3x}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}\Big|= \infty,$$concluding the convergence is not uniform!

Comment: I still don't understand why the function need to be uniformly continuous

Comment: see my edit.....

Comment: Ok, isee brother thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

rather than have $n\to\infty$ we can say $\delta x\to0^+$ from $\delta x=\frac{1}{n}$ and then we get:
$$\lim_{\delta x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}=f'(x)$$
this is of course dependent on that fact that $f$ is a continuous function for the range we are looking at and is differentiable on this set. Now you need to consider if this function is continuous.

Comment: Okay, if we assume this function is continuous how to prove this function is uniformly converges to $f'$?

Comment: Something like the taylor expansion of $f(x)$ then taking the limit would work